# Extending a hexadecimal number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

So I have the following hex number :

```
 0x55 which is 0101 0101
```

And I need to extend it to 0x55555555. Only ops I can use are the following:

```
Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
```

I'm a little confused on how I should that. I know we have to move left for sure though. I'm sure this is an easy question so I apologize, I just can't think at this point anymore..

Comment: Well, you have 8 bits and need to make 3 additional copies. One way is to make a single copy to get a 16-bit number and then make 2 copies of that, so you have 32.  To copy, shift the necessary number of bits left and "or" with the original.  `unsigned x = 0x55; x |= x << 8; x |= x << 16; printf("%x\n", x);`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now! Thanks @Gene

Comment: If you aren't "allowed" to use the assignment operators, tough luck, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    unsigned int orig = 0x55;
    unsigned int new;

    new = orig | orig << 8 | orig << 16 | orig << 24;

    printf( "orig: 0x%x\n", orig );
    printf( "new:  0x%x\n", new );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
orig: 0x55
new:  0x55555555
```

Comment: The op isn't "allowed" to use the assignment operator.